# My device keeps switching network from internet to extension

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, extension

so basically I have an network extension, when your router is not long enough to reach the whole house, there is an extension that extends it. the problem however is that my device keeps switching network from internet to extension, oops while I was writing this, it connected to the extension, making it no internet for a few seconds, this is a big problem because I'm a game developer and I need straight connection.

Comment: You could have 2 separate wifi networks so that you have to manually switch between the two access points.

Comment: @Natecat AFAIK, when you have an access point configured, it's configured with a separate WiFi network, however it's not for client devices but solely for connecting the access point to the main wireless router/another access point. This allows a client device to use the same WiFi network across all access points, as the purpose of the access point is to extend the range of the main WiFi network.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows - Make sure the "Connect Automatically" box is *un*checked on the other network you don't want to connect to all the time.

[image]